# enforce primary key to exist in another multi colum primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, relationship, reverse

I have two tables. First table has multi columns as the primary key and the second table has one column primary key. Data has be entered first in Table1 `FieldPlacement` where `FieldPlacementNum` will be generated then enter a record in Table2 where the `FieldPlacementNum` has to exist in Table1.

Currently has one to many relationship but I want the reverse the relationship of tables and SQL does not let me do it. thanks

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FieldPlacement]
(
    [ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Year] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Term] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PlacementNum] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](70) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FieldPlacement] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [Year] ASC, [Term] ASC, [PlacementNum] ASC)
      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FieldPlacement] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FieldPlacement_FieldPlacementEval1] 
   FOREIGN KEY([PlacementNum])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[FieldPlacementEval] ([PlacementNum])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FieldPlacement] 
   CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FieldPlacement_FieldPlacementEval1]
GO
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FieldPlacementEval]
(
    [PlacementNum] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentLastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [StudentFirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TeacherLastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TeacherFirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_FieldPlacementEval] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PlacementNum] ASC)
      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
            IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Since the PK of `FieldPlacement` consists of four columns, any foreign key relation to that PK *also* must have all four columns. No way around that. What you *could* do is create an unique index on `FieldPlacement.PlacementNum` - that way, your second table could reference that unique, non-null index as a foreign key

Comment: Also: since `FieldPlacement.PlacementNum`  is an `IDENTITY`; you could also make **this** your PK, and then just create a unique index on those four columns that currently make up the PK (to ensure their uniqueness) and then just reference the new PK on just `PlacementNum`. The additional benefit here would be a smaller, more efficient clustering key on your `FieldPlacement` table (since it's only 1 column instead of 4 - and skips all those variable length columns which are really bad for a clustering key)

Comment: This comment by @marc_s should be an answer (and it should be accepted).

Comment: If the PlacementNum is an identity field in 1 table and the primary key of the other, and you have to match rows, why do you need 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

Since `FieldPlacement.PlacementNum` is an `IDENTITY`, which is `NOT NULL` and unique, you could also make this your PK, and then just create a unique index on those four columns that currently make up the PK (to ensure their uniqueness).

From your `FieldPlacementEval` just reference the `PlacementNum`.

The additional benefit here would be a smaller, more efficient clustering key on your `FieldPlacement` table (since it's only 1 column instead of 4 - and skips all those variable length columns which are really bad for a clustering key)